How can I animate a droplet landing on a flat surface?



I want a spherical droplet to land and spread out from the bottom, the way an ink droplet would behave. I am trying to keep this simple, as far as modifiers go. It's going to be in slow motion, so making it look accurate is a little more important. Maybe it's better to use shapekeys.

is it supposed to separate? Yes shapekeys is a good idea

No separation. Just a very basic fluid animation of a droplet landing.

So have you tried shapekeys and what difficulty have you met?

I tried creating a shapekey with proportional editing. I pulled the bottom vertex up and created the mesh you see here. The problem with that is that when a droplet hits the ground the bottom area should increase and not simply go into the mesh. I was hoping whatever solution we arrive at would maintain the volume of the original mesh and also behave like a droplet hitting the surface.
